# Delete selection gap in Inkscape

Tags: inkscape, selections

I selected two objects. As you can see at the screenshot the upper one has a selection gap and a lower one does not.

How can I delete the gap of the upper one? I need this in order to be able to export the object as a `.png`.

[image]

Comment: It's nearly impossible to tell from a screenshot. Share a link to the SVG please.

Comment: What service can I use to share .svg?

Comment: Try filedropper, dropbox, onedrive, or google drive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

draw a rectangle the same size as your image over the top of the other one select the outer rectangle then the one you just drawn then--
 object, set, clip .. the outer area is from the blurring of the zig-zags

Comment: It works! Thank you for the attention. But why does it work and are there easier ways to do it?

Comment: another way would be to select your green background rectangle and in the save png dialogue select export selection. but the way I described is the tidy way